# How to disable the CapLock?

Tags: keyboard

Just installed 13.10, and the one of the first things i always do in a new install, is to disable capslock. But i can't find the keyboard options anymore?

Comment: Ubuntu 13.10 is not yet released so for now at least the question is [off topic](http://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask).  You may want to ask on Ubuntu Forums: [Ubuntu +1](http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=427) or report it as a bug on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu)

Comment: @WarrenHill: Please have a look at this: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7363/are-answers-about-beta-versions-of-ubuntu-accepted?cb=1

Comment: @Jobin: It clearly states [here](http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) that this site is **not** the right place for questions questions about issues with alpha and beta releases.

Comment: 13.10 has now been released, and this is still an issue. Should someone vote to reopen it, or is it still off topic for something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I created an Autostart with the command

```
setxkbmap -option caps:none
```

*Startup Applications* > *Add* > *Name*: Disable Capslock > *Command*: setxkbmap -option caps:none > *Add*.

Restart and capslock is disabled. Works also in Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This is pure gold, for more than one reason. Can all or most commands be run like this?

Comment: @mote: I guess you can run many commands via startup applications. E.g. I use a startup application to delete all thumbnails (command: rm -r /home/<username>/.cache/thumbnails). Just try. A more professional way is to define cronejobs, but I'm just an ordinary user.

Answer (score 10):

The graphical options for keyboard layout seem to have changed. You can do it via terminal though. Open a terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and then do then:

```
setxkbmap -option caps:none
```

The above may not work on newer versions of Ubuntu. Try this instead:

```
setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps
```

To re-enable them:

```
setxkbmap -option
```

To make this happen at every reboot, write the command to a file and store it in a convinient location(the filesystem should be ext4 where you would store the file) and then on a terminal, type `crontab -e` and then add this line to the end of the file that opens up(it may ask you to set the editor by which it should open, I prefer `nano` or `vim.full`:

```
@reboot /path/to/the/script
```

Comment: How can i make this permanent?
- I guess i need some help making a script and running it at login.
Thanks

Comment: @mote: edited my answer, please have a look.

Comment: You can look at a list of other options at in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst`

Comment: `setxkbmap -option caps:none` not working (Lubuntu 13.04).

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich: 13.04 is no more supported.

Comment: @Jobin Sorry, I mean 13.10 - any solution?

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich: This has been tested to work on 13.10, if it doesn't work for you, post a question describing what hasn't worked and what you tried.

Comment: @i08in  Interestingly the caps key still works when you're in an rdesktop session to windoze. Is there a way to disable that too, maybe at a lower level? Hopefully not quite as low as screwdriver + superglue  ;p

Answer (score 0):

This one works without restart everytime:

> setxkbmap -layout us -option caps:ctrl_modifier  gsettings set
>
> org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['caps:ctrl_modifier']"